# I'm getting an import error with ydata-profiling-4.4.0: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I know that Pydantic V2 introduced new things which make it incompatible with V1, so I switched from pandas_profiling to ydata_profiling. Because of that, I had to switch versions of the dependencies, but now I'm getting a complex error which makes it seem like there's now way to resolve all three of my resulting errors at once:

```
pydantic-settings 2.0.2 requires pydantic>=2.0.1, but you have pydantic 1.8.1 which is incompatible.
ydata-profiling 4.4.0 requires pydantic<2,>=1.8.1, but you have pydantic 2.1.1 which is incompatible.
```

Is there anyway to make this code work using ydata or should I switch over to a different library. Currently on Windows 11 and python version 3.11.0.

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

choice = st.radio("Navigation", ["Upload", "Profiling", "ML", "Download", "Predictions"])

if choice == "Profiling":
    profile_report = ProfileReport(df, title="Profiling Report")
    st_profile_report(profile_report)
#Imported the ProfileReport function from ydata_profiling and resulted in the error previously showed.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.